# Proof that there is always irreducible polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

[image: I have to show $d|n]

I do not really understand about this paragraph
In this proof, what is meant by the leading term $p^n$ will dominate the remaining terms?

and also, how he conclude in the end that $\sigma(n)>0$? (Because I only see he proved that $n\sigma(n)<p^n$.)

Comment: Keep your eye on the ball! The proof is about *the remaining terms*. That is, the terms with $d<n$. They show that $$\left\vert\sum_{d\mid n, d<n}\mu(n/d)p^d\right\vert<p^n.$$ Therefore
$$|n\sigma(n)-p^n|=\left\vert\sum_{d\mid n, d<n}\mu(n/d)p^d\right\vert<p^n.$$
Therefore $n\sigma(n)>0$.

Comment: See the last part of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125854/11619).

Answer (score 2):

He is saying that $$n\sigma(n)=p^n+\sum_{d\mid n,d<n}\mu(n/d)p^d$$
and that
$$\left|\sum_{d\mid n,d<n}\mu(n/d)p^d\right|\le\sum_{e=0}^{n-1}p^e
=\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}<p^n.$$
This then implies that $n\sigma(n)>0$.